# Batch Delete in Core Data Swift 5.x

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, reset, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I was trying to delete entity in batch.

```swift
try myNSManagedObjectContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest)
```

After this should I use `myNSManagedObjectContext.reset()` or `myNSManagedObjectContext.save()`

Using `myNSManagedObjectContext.reset()` crashing on the device.

Comment: Is there any kind of error message when this happens?

Comment: it just crashes... there is Refresh button on my screen. After pressing I get some json from the server, then I parse it and before saving I just delete old entries.... so on reset() it crashes

Comment: This is Crashlytics log
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000480102a90

0 libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 20
1 CoreData -[NSManagedObjectContext reset] + 344